# Django queryset get empty values in query

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

So I'm trying to get all the values to be able to display in my templates. However I have encountered myself with this problem:

I have these models:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    projectId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column="Id", db_index=True, verbose_name='Project ID')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=900)

class PM(models.Model):
    PMid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column="Id", db_index=True)
    PMNumber = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, db_column="PMNumber")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=600)
    projectId = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                  db_column="ProjectID", related_name='+')
```

And I'm trying to get all the projects with their respective PMNumber. For which I'm trying something like this:

```
fpm = PM.objects.all()
projects = []
for i in fpm:
   projects.append({'ProjectName': i.projectId.description, 'PMNumber': i.PMNumber})
```

After that the result is like this

```
[{'ProjectName': 'pr1', 'PMNumber': '119508-01'}, {'ProjectName': 'pr1', 'PMNumber': '119490-01'}]
```

However, I'm still missing some projects that don't have a PM related to them, I want all the projects in the queryset to be able to show them in a template, not just the ones that have a PM. It should look something like this:

```
[{'ProjectName': 'pr2', 'PMNumber':'None'}, {'ProjectName':'pr3' , 'PMNumber':'None'}, {'ProjectName': 'pr1', 'PMNumber': '119508-01'}, {'ProjectName': 'pr1', 'PMNumber': '119490-01'}]
```

Is there a way to do this? or is there another way to do this in the views?

Note: I know that setting an ID for each class in Django is not right, but it's kind of a standard in the place where I work at. So I can't change it.

Comment: I see a syntax error in `projects.append`. Dict never opened?

Comment: Yes you're right, it was just a syntax error when I wrote the question. It is well written in the code. I edited the question already. Thank you for noticing :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should then do this the opposite way:

```
result = list(Project.objects.values(
    'description',
    ProjectName=F('pm__PMNumber')
))
```

For the `Project`s for which no `PM` exists, `None` will be used for `ProjectName`. If there are multiple `PM`s for the same `Project`, all these `PM`s will be added.

That being said, I do not see why you set `related_name` to `realted_name='+'`. This is the name of the relation in reverse, so likely it is better to set it to something like:

```
class PM(models.Model):
    PMid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column="Id", db_index=True)
    PMNumber = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, db_column="PMNumber")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=600)
    projectId = models.ForeignKey(
        Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        db_column="ProjectID",
        related_name='pm_set'
)
```

Then you query with:

```
result = list(Project.objects.values(
    'description',
    ProjectName=F('pm_set__PMNumber')
))
```

You can replace a missing `ProjectName` with the `description` of the project with:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

result = list(Project.objects.values(
    'description',
    ProjectName=Coalesce('pm_set__PMNumber', 'description')
))
```

You can also post-process the list to a dictionary that contains dictionaries where the `projectName` (or perhaps better `projectNames` is a *list*, with:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

result = list(Project.objects.values(
    'description',
    ProjectName=Coalesce('pm_set__PMNumber', 'description')
).order_by('description'))

result = [ 
    { 'description': k, 'projectNames': list(map(itemgetter('projectName'), vs)) }
    for k, vs in groupby(itemgetter('description'), result)
]
```

or we can make an empty list for `Projects` with no `PM` with:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

result = list(Project.objects.values(
    'description',
    ProjectName=F('pm_set__PMNumber')
).order_by('description'))

result = [ 
    { 'description': k, 'projectNames': list(filter(None, map(itemgetter('projectName'), vs))) }
    for k, vs in groupby(itemgetter('description'), result)
]
```

Comment: Oh, I used it in that way so I would be able to see it in the Django Admin as part of another model, I wasn't able to add it in the right way. Should I change it anyway?
And I understand what you wrote, but I need the ProjectName to not be empty and the PM empty if it does not have anything. Can I do that?

Comment: @DiegoDuarte: Given the `PM` does not exists, exactly *what* should be put in the `ProjectName`?

Comment: Let me get a better context: I'm trying to display all the available projects in a list in a HTML template, but I also need the ```PMs``` from the projects that have them to be able to show which ones have a ```PM``` and which ones don't. So given the fact that the ```PM``` does not exist, the ```ProjectName``` should be the same than the ```description``` from the project. I hope it makes sense

Comment: It should look something like this:
```Project1: PMS: 10292, 10282```,
```Project2:```, 
```Project3: PMS: xxxx, xxxx```

Comment: @DiegoDuarte: perhaps you can take a look at the output generated by the possible answers, and comment on what needs to be changed.

Comment: This ```from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

result = list(Project.objects.values(
    'description',
    ProjectName=Coalesce('pm_set__PMNumber', 'description')
))``` and  this 
```result = list(Project.objects.values(
    'description',
    ProjectName=Coalesce('pm_set__PMNumber', 'description')
).order_by('description'))

result = [ 
    { 'description': k, 'projectNames': list(map(itemgetter('projectName'), vs)) }
    for k, vs in groupby(itemgetter('description'), result)
]```
are what I was looking for, thanks a lot!